# How do you build training dataset from scratch for a custom multi-class standfordNLP/Stanza NER tagging model in BIOES/BILOU format?

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am utilizing NLP for a custom application and I want to train my own NER tagger model in StanfordNLP currently known as Stanza.

The default model is limited to very general tags such as LOC, PER, MISC, COUNTRY, TIME etc.

My custom tags are more specific ex. Food, Sport, Software, Brand. How would I got about formatting data I **scraped** off of the web or from PDF files in BIOES/BILOU format?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside%E2%80%93outside%E2%80%93beginning_(tagging)

Do I necessarily have to tag them manually? or write a script to generate the data in the format shown below:

```
Alex S-PER
is O
playing O
basketball I-SPORT
with O
Marty B-PER
. O
Rick E-PER
likes O
to O
eat O
Pizza I-FOOD
in O
Los B-LOC
Angeles E-LOC
```

If so then what tools and libraries can I use in Python?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to annotate your own dataset. This is inevitable (unless we have already tagged data). You can make use of [doccano](https://github.com/doccano/doccano) + small snippet of code to fasten up the process

Answer (score 3):

you can write a piece of code to achieve this task.

Here is a solution I made.

```
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
import stanza
nlp = stanza.Pipeline(lang='en', processors='tokenize,ner,pos')


# Tag tokens with standard NLP BIO tags
def bio_tagger(entity, start_char, end_char, tag):
    bio_tagged = {"tag":None, "end_char":None, "start_char":None}
    ne_tagged = entity.split()
    if len(ne_tagged) == 1:
        bio_tagged["start_char"] = start_char
        bio_tagged["end_char"] = start_char + len(ne_tagged[0])
        bio_tagged["tag"] = "B-"+tag
    elif len(ne_tagged) == 2:
        bio_tagged["start_char"] = start_char
        bio_tagged["end_char"] = start_char + len(ne_tagged[0])
        bio_tagged["tag"] = "B-"+tag

        bio_tagged["start_char"] = end_char - len(ne_tagged[-1])
        bio_tagged["end_char"] = end_char 
        bio_tagged["tag"] = "E-"+tag
    elif len(ne_tagged) >= 3:
        bio_tagged["start_char"] = start_char
        bio_tagged["end_char"] = start_char + len(ne_tagged[0])
        bio_tagged["tag"] = "B-"+tag

        bio_tagged["start_char"] = end_char - len(ne_tagged[-1])
        bio_tagged["end_char"] = end_char 
        bio_tagged["tag"] = "E-"+tag

        cursor = start_char + len(ne_tagged[0]) + 2
        for tok in ne_tagged[1:-1]:
            bio_tagged["start_char"] = cursor
            bio_tagged["end_char"] = cursor + len(tok) 
            bio_tagged["tag"] = "I-"+tag
            cursor = cursor + len(tok)  + 2
    return bio_tagged


def bio_corpus_builder(text, tags2dict):
    #tags2dict {'SPORT':['football','basektball'],
    #           'FOOD':['banana','orange']}
    corpus = []
    document = []

    for tag, tag_values in tags2dict.items():
        keyword_processor = KeywordProcessor()
        keyword_processor.add_keywords_from_list(tag_values)

        for sent in get_sentences(text):
            word_tag_tagger = []
            each_token = {"text": None, "upos":None, "xpos":None,"tag":None, "end_char":None, "start_char":None}
            entities_found = keyword_processor.extract_keywords(sent, span_info=True)
            if entities_found:
                # construct custom tag
                for word_tag in entities_found:
                    word_tag_tagger.append(bio_tagger(word_tag[0], word_tag[1], word_tag[2], tag))
                # read original tag  
                doc = nlp(sent)
                sentence = doc.sentences[0]
                print(word_tag_tagger)
                each_sent = []
                for token in sentence.tokens:
                    each_token["text"] = token.text
                    each_token["tag"] = token.ner
                    each_token["end_char"] = token.end_char
                    each_token["start_char"] = token.start_char
                    each_token["upos"] = token.to_dict()[0]["upos"]
                    each_token["xpos"] = token.to_dict()[0]["xpos"]

                    each_sent.append(dict(each_token))

                #update tagging
                for tok in each_sent:
                    for word2tags in word_tag_tagger:
                        if (int(tok["start_char"]) == int(word2tags["start_char"])) and (int(tok["end_char"]) == int(word2tags["end_char"])):
                            tok["tag"] = word2tags['tag']


                document.append(each_sent)
        del keyword_processor
    return document


# if "__name__"=="__main__":
tags2dict ={'SPORT':['football','basektball'],'FOOD':['banana','orange']}
text = "Barack Obama was born in Hawaii. He love basektball."

bio_corpus_builder(text, tags2dict)

#output
# [[{'text': 'He',
#    'upos': 'PRON',
#    'xpos': 'PRP',
#    'tag': 'O',
#    'end_char': 2,
#    'start_char': 0},
#   {'text': 'love',
#    'upos': 'VERB',
#    'xpos': 'VBP',
#    'tag': 'O',
#    'end_char': 7,
#    'start_char': 3},
#   {'text': 'basektball',
#    'upos': 'NOUN',
#    'xpos': 'NN',
#    'tag': 'B-SPORT',
#    'end_char': 18,
#    'start_char': 8},
#   {'text': '.',
#    'upos': 'PUNCT',
#    'xpos': '.',
#    'tag': 'O',
#    'end_char': 19,
#    'start_char': 18}]]
```